# calculate income variance based on categorical income data

Tags: variance, survival

I would like to calculate the variance of household income in a city. Income data at the individual household level,however, are not available from Census. What we have are categorical income data at the city and census tract levels (number of households in each income interval). Is there a way that I can estimate the variance of household income from the Census income interval data?

I have read some relevant literature and they suggest to use survival model to estimate income variance from Census interval income data. But I was not able to find detailed methods to do it.

Comment: You can use what is called Sheppard correction, see http://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/basic-statistics/sheppard-corrections-and-corrected-coefficient-of-variation.html  or  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheppard's_correction